# Как при прокрутке изменить стиль?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующий код.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop(0)) {
 $('#console').css('background','blue'); 
 }
 else {
 $(window).on('scroll',function(){ 
    $('#console').css('background','red'); 
});
 }
```

При прокрутке должен меняться фон, но при возвращении скролла на самый верх фон должен возвращаться.

Он к сожалению не рабочий.
Как можно сделать что бы при прокрутке стиль менялся?
http://jsfiddle.net/FhRKU/39/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Проверять `.scrollTop()` нужно так: `if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0)`;
2. `$(window).on('scroll')` нужно вызывать не из условия. Сейчас у вас получается, что если прокрутка посетителя находится в самом верху, то обработчик и не объявляется.
3. Всю проверку и смену стилей лучше вынести в отдельную функцию и
   вызывать ее как при загрузке страницы, так и при скролле страницы.

```js
function consoleBG() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $('#console').css('background', 'blue');
  } else {
    $('#console').css('background', 'red');
  }
}
consoleBG();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  consoleBG();
});
```

```css
#console {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="console"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>dfsdsd
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>trhrth
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>rfwerfwe
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Не подумал о вызове функции почему то...